# iPhone App - change directory dependencies

Tags: ios, directory, dependencies, ipa

I wanted to know, if its possible to change the dependency of some directories.

To be specific:

In the app there are several information/pictures stored in an own-created (from the app after installing) directory called "Library". I cant access this directory from an unjailbroken device. But there is a directory called "Documents" which can be accessed from iTunes.

I want to change the dependency or whatever, so that I can grap or put on files in the "Documents" folder and the app will take them as well from there.
I tried to unzip the file and I had a look into some files but none of them contained a path to those directories. The only file remained was (I guess) the executable compiled file, which I could not encrypt/open/change.

Sorry for bad description - Im not sure how to depict it better.

Comment: Could you show some of your code?  How are you accessing the Library directory?

Comment: There is no code. Im accessing the Library directory from an old iPhone 4 that is already jailbroken.
I can simply paste the files into that directory and it works fine. But with the unjailbroken phone I have no access to that directory, so I search a method to change the path or let the app install the files from its own.

Or can I write an app that can change files in another app?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for getting help solving programming problems.  If you are trying to hack something else and are not writing your own code, it is not a question for Stack Overflow.  You might be able to find help at https://superuser.com.

Comment: Its not hacking an app. Just wanted to change a map-package that was better before the update came out.
Thanks anyway, i'll try at superuser.com.